# How to change the width and color of the box frame in psxy plot

Tags: bash, plot, awk, pygmt

i want to plot a gmt graph using psxy command and the three column data attached below, however i need to change the box frame width and its color to blue instead of default black. I tried the below code but it doesn’t change the box frame color to blue and it’s width.i am using GMT version 5.3 in ubuntu platform.

```
#!/bin/sh

awk ‘{print $2, $3}’ neq.data | gmt psxy -R1960/2000/0/30 -JX5/8 -Sb0.1 -G255/0/0
-Ba10f5/a5f1 -W9/0/0/250 -P -K -X5 -Y8 >tmp.ps

gs tmp.ps
```

data is attached here in the name of neq.data

```
01 1963 11
02 1964 8
03 1965 8
04 1966 4
05 1967 0
```

Comment: please provide me a link where i can provide my code and data

Comment: click the [edit] button under your question and just copy/paste from your desktop.

Comment: Since there were major changes introduced in GMT 6 I recommend to update to the most recent version.

Comment: You have to set the MAP_FRAME_PEN parameter to blue to change the frame color. An example: 
`echo "0.5 0.5 " | gmt psxy -R0/1/0/1 -JX5 -Sc.5 -Gred --MAP_FRAME_PEN=blue -B1 > temp.ps`